# Reset dates Range of in between dates in POSTGRES function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a date ranges of start date and end date like

```
'2017-01-01', '2017-01-31'
'2017-01-04', '2017-02-20'
'2017-02-21', '2017-03-29'
'2017-03-17', '2017-04-12'
```

I need a output as

```
'2017-01-01', '2017-02-20'
'2017-02-21', '2017-04-12'
```

Is there any possibility of getting output using only postgres function? can someone please help me.

Comment: What is the logic for getting that result from the data?

Answer (score 0):

I feel that similar question is asked so many times, I should write an explanation behind possible logic, so I added one more row to introduce the problem (otherwise you could just compare pairs, not the trees):

```
t=# insert into t select '2017-01-08','2017-02-12';
INSERT 0 1
```

now the "logic":

```
t=# with c as (select daterange(s,e), s,e, daterange(s,e) && lead(daterange(s,e)) over (order by s) ovps from t)
select *, case when not lag(ovps) over (order by s) or row_number() over (order by s) = 1 then s end strt, case when not ovps or row_number() over (order by s) = count(1) over () then e end fnsh
from c;
        daterange        |     s      |     e      | ovps |    strt    |    fnsh
-------------------------+------------+------------+------+------------+------------
 [2017-01-01,2017-01-31) | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-31 | t    | 2017-01-01 |
 [2017-01-04,2017-02-20) | 2017-01-04 | 2017-02-20 | t    |            |
 [2017-01-08,2017-02-12) | 2017-01-08 | 2017-02-12 | f    |            | 2017-02-12
 [2017-02-21,2017-03-29) | 2017-02-21 | 2017-03-29 | t    | 2017-02-21 |
 [2017-03-17,2017-04-12) | 2017-03-17 | 2017-04-12 |      |            | 2017-04-12
(5 rows)
```

I know I'm inventing a wheel here, but somebody should show HOW it works. So the above **ovps** column shows if ranges overlaps, **strt** and **fnsh** are respectively start and finish of resulting ranges ordered by **s** (which is the original start from original data set before collapsing)...

next:

```
t=# with c as (select daterange(s,e), s,e, daterange(s,e) && lead(daterange(s,e)) over (order by s) ovps from t)
, n as (select *, case when not lag(ovps) over (order by s) or row_number() over (order by s) = 1 then s end strt, case when not ovps or row_number() over (order by s) = count(1) over () then e end fnsh
from c)
select daterange, strt, fnsh, dense_rank() over (order by strt), dense_rank() over (order by fnsh) from n order by s;
        daterange        |    strt    |    fnsh    | dense_rank | dense_rank
-------------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------
 [2017-01-01,2017-01-31) | 2017-01-01 |            |          1 |          3
 [2017-01-04,2017-02-20) |            |            |          3 |          3
 [2017-01-08,2017-02-12) |            | 2017-02-12 |          3 |          1
 [2017-02-21,2017-03-29) | 2017-02-21 |            |          2 |          3
 [2017-03-17,2017-04-12) |            | 2017-04-12 |          3 |          2
(5 rows)
```

we `dense_rank` to get when the date is met in the order (NULLs last). Now that we have the order when the value is met, we can just get min and maxover the least value:

```
t=# with c as (select daterange(s,e), s,e, daterange(s,e) && lead(daterange(s,e)) over (order by s) ovps from t)
, n as (select *, case when not lag(ovps) over (order by s) or row_number() over (order by s) = 1 then s end strt, case when not ovps or row_number() over (order by s) = count(1) over () then e end fnsh
from c)
, d as (select daterange, strt, fnsh, dense_rank() over (order by strt) ds, dense_rank() over (order by fnsh) de from n order by s)
select distinct min(strt) over (partition by least(ds,de)), max(fnsh) over (partition by least(ds,de)) from d;
    min     |    max
------------+------------
            |
 2017-02-21 | 2017-04-12
 2017-01-01 | 2017-02-12
(3 rows)
```

now remove null row and order properly:

```
t=# with c as (select daterange(s,e), s,e, daterange(s,e) && lead(daterange(s,e)) over (order by s) ovps from t)
, n as (select *, case when not lag(ovps) over (order by s) or row_number() over (order by s) = 1 then s end strt, case when not ovps or row_number() over (order by s) = count(1) over () then e end fnsh
from c)
, d as (select daterange, strt, fnsh, dense_rank() over (order by strt) ds, dense_rank() over (order by fnsh) de from n order by s)
, f as (select distinct min(strt) over (partition by least(ds,de)), max(fnsh) over (partition by least(ds,de)) from d)
select min startc, max endc from f where min is not null order by min;
   startc   |    endc
------------+------------
 2017-01-01 | 2017-02-12
 2017-02-21 | 2017-04-12
(2 rows)
```

Finally I'm pretty sure you can reduce most of "the logic" mathematically and make it neat...